# Eclipse IDE internal project representaion

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

Currently I'm trying to write a tool for migration from Eclipse IDE to Intellij Idea specifically for my project.

For now, the main question is how and where Eclipse store project information (i.e. libraries, dependencies between app modules and so on) internally.

P.S.
The Intellij's migration tool does not work for my project.

*Update:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredPlugins"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="generated/" kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Please post the content of your .classpath file. That will help folks to help you figure our where the rest of the dependency information is located. An entry in .classpath can be dynamic, resolving based on metadata stored elsewhere.

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik, I've updated the post with content of .classpath file.

Comment: Judging by "org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredPlugins" entry, you have an Eclipse plugin or an OSGi bundle project. How do you expect to migrate to IntelliJ? I don't believe it has any tooling for this. In Eclipse, PDE will resolve the bundles and packages referenced in your project's manifest against the target platform defined in the workspace to compute the project's classpath.

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik, it seems you're right. This module is an OSGI bundle. Also, according to http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/osgi.html, IntelliJ IDEA supports OSGI projects, but for some reason it doesn't work for me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Everything that eclipse keeps on your project is stored in the .settings folder (containing a.o. .project and .classpath).

But unless you have some very specific setup you should be able to import your project into IntelliJ without any hassle. Even if it's not, I would expect that setting up the project manually in IntelliJ will be a lot faster than writing a tool for it.

Comment: As I wrote in my post, the project can't be imported using Intellij. Also, the tool can be reused to help my colleagues to migrate as well. Actually, I have already checked these files (org.eclipse.*.core.prefs from .settings, .classpath and .project), but I haven't found info about used libraries and module dependencies.

Comment: @pbespechnyi Project dependencies are in the .classpath file.

Comment: @pbespechnyi All the information is in those files. Otherwise it would not even be possible to open the project in a new eclipse installation for instance.

Comment: @StijnGeukens, I've added content of .classpath file.